# jQuery radio group validation and enable option if certain radio checked (jsfiddle provided)

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button

I am new to jQuery.

How would I go about checking to see if one of the radio buttons is checked, and if other is checked, then enable the text option.  If not, then disable it.  I didn't put full code here, but it is more or less the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/Opetus/8Ahcz/

HTML
    `<table> 
      <tr>
        <td id="second">
          <input type="radio" name="inquire" id="9" class="css-checkbox"/>
          <label for="9" class="css-label radGroup1 radGroup2">3D</label>
        </td>
        <td id="second">
          <input type="radio" name="inquire" id="10" class="css-checkbox" />
          <label for="10" class="css-label radGroup1 radGroup2">Coding</label>
        </td>
        <td id="opt">
          <input type="radio" name="inquire" id="11" class="css-checkbox" />
          <label for="11" class="css-label radGroup1 radGroup2">Other:</label>
          <input type="text" name="other" id="other" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>`

**Answered**

```
`$('.css-checkbox').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
     if($(this).attr('id') == 11)
         $('#other').prop('disabled', false);
     else
     {
        $('#other').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#other').val('');
     }
  });`
```

**Note**
If adding a color box to this, put color-box code AFTER the answer above.  If not, it will void the submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/8Ahcz/3/

I just added this code.

```
   $('.css-checkbox').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
     if($(this).attr('id') == 11)
         $('#other').prop('disabled', false);
     else
     {
        $('#other').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#other').val('');
     }
  });
```

I have made the changes do check.

Comment: other is still editable if a different radio button is checked

Comment: Plz check now. I have made the changes. And you would also need to disable it if other is clicked right.

Comment: @KelliHaggett LOL. hhahahha. If you find the new updated fiddle right then plz upvote the answer and mark it as right answer. So that it will go out the unanswered queue

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle. Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/vkvikram020/Pue3X/

Jquery Code is

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){    
//alert($('input:radio:checked').attr('id'));
var selectedID=$('input:radio:checked').attr('id');
if(selectedID==11){
    $('#other').attr("disabled", false);
}
else{
    $('#other').val("");
    $('#other').attr("disabled", true);
}
selectedID=0;
})
```